# Save changed image in c# using graphic and bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

I read an image and print some text on it as you can see .

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"d:\a.jpg");
RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(70, 90, 90, 50);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
g.DrawString("yourText", new Font("Tahoma", 8), Brushes.Black, rectf);
g.Flush();
```

How can i save my image and  these changes in another location of my computer ?

Comment: How did you figure all that out but miss the Save() method?

Comment: @Crowcoder you mean g.save()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dispose `Graphics` object

```
g.Dispose();
```

And save Bitmap

```
bmp.Save(fileName);
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you have all Bitmap methods include different versions of `Save`

Comment: the changes are saved ?